# Using request module and passing the body to the next request

Tags: node.js, request, multipartform-data, form-data

I am using request to get an image:

`request(req.body.imageUrl, {encoding: null}, function(error, response, body) {`

I then want to use the body to pass to an api that uses a multipart form and send that image (which is now in the body).  I don't want to write the file to disk and then readstream from the disk again.  I basically want to enter the formData of the next request by using the Buffer of the body, but it is not working.

So, for the options in the next request I have:

```
const options = {
                method: "POST",
                url: coreURL,
                headers: {
                    "Content-Type": "multipart/form-data"
                },
                formData : {
                    file : new Buffer.from(body,'binary')
                }
            };
```

And this does not work, if I write the body to a file `fs.writeFileSync(fileName, body, 'binary');`

And then read in the options `formData : { file : fs.createReadStream(fileName)}`

it works but I cannot use the disk, so need an alternative way to pass the body into the next post as multipart form data.

Any ideas?

Comment: You need to post your full / surrounding code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

POC:

```js
let request = require('request');

request.post({
        url: "http://httpbin.org/anything",
        formData: {
            myfile: request.get("https://www.gravatar.com/avatar/f056d36f9e273fd4740ec8a5cea1348a"),
        }
    },
    function (err, req, body) {
        console.log(body);
    }
);
```